# PHP setcookie - expiration date does not apply

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I am setting some cookies in this way:

```
session_start();
$cookie_name = 'remember_me@website.com';
$cookie_time = time() + 315360000;
setcookie($cookie_name, 'username='.$cookie_username.'&hash='.$cookie_password, $cookie_time, '/', '.website.com');
```

Using the Firefox dev console, I am able to see that the cookie is set, however its expiration date is 21.01.1970, 5:00:44. Can anybody explain what is going on here?

Comment: '/', '.website.com'  to '.website.com'

Comment: @BuseGönen 4th param is path, 5th param is domain

Comment: edit cookie_name $cookie_name = 'remember_me@website.com';

Comment: @BuseGönen edit.. how? Anything wrong there? because with my current setup i only get issue with expiration time

Comment: I'm guessing. Try the odds. Sory, my English not good.

Comment: This is 10 years in the future right? What if you try 5?
$cookie_time = time() + 157680000;

Comment: @thanpa i changed to a year, tried a day and whatever, i get expiration date near 1970 or until browser close :/

Answer (score 0):

OK let's see. I run the code on my own machine and the cookie was set as good as expected. So I think that your date in the server is set wrong. Which means the time() method probably returns a time after 2028, which results to a cookie to be expiring on 2038 which is not possible and it will have unexpected results on the expiring date set.

Comment: My cookie time is 10 years? O.o seems like there is one odd zero. Anyway, im using `time()` for many things on the same server and it works properly :/ Ill make some tests tomorrow, anyway thank you for ur suggestion